# Kendo Tabstrip Razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-asp.net-mvc, razor-2, kendo-tabstrip

As part of converting a ASPX page to Razor MVC5 page, i came across Kendo Tabstrip used in our application which has the following syntax in aspx

```
tabstrip.Add()
                                                .Text(item.Title)
                                                //.HtmlAttributes(new { tabindex = "-1" })
                                                .Selected(true)
                                                .Content(() =>
                                                { 
                                                    %> 
                                                    <div style="width:980px; min-height:562px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px">
                                                    <% 
                                                    using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "tabForm" }))
                                                    {%>
                                                            <div>
                                                                <%: Html.ValidationSummary(false)%>
                                                                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div style="padding-top:30px; text-align:center;">

</div>
                                                            <%: Html.Hidden("NextActionHelper", Model.NextActionHelper)%>
                                                            <%: Html.Hidden("UserFormAction", Model.UserFormAction)%>

                                                        <%
                                                    }
                                                        %>
                                                    </div>
                                                <%
                                                });
```

I am getting a semi colon missing error when i use the below code, which is in razor, but I want to know the proper tag to make the div valid.
That is  I am using @ before the first div tag, right after .Content, which doesnt seem valid, but unless i put it there, the div appears as free text with squiggly lines. What is the right syntax to make razor recognize the div tags?

```
tabstrip.Add()
                                .Text(item.Title)
                                .Selected(true)
                                .Content(() =>
                                {
                                    @<div style="width:980px; min-height:562px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px">

                                    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "tabForm" }))
                                    {
                                    <div>
                                        @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
                                        @RenderBody()
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="padding-top:30px; text-align:center;">
Some stuff in between
</div>
                                        @Html.Hidden("NextActionHelper", Model.NextActionHelper)
                                        @Html.Hidden("UserFormAction", Model.UserFormAction)
                                    }
                                    </div>



                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the code below. It uses an other overload of the "Content" method.

```
tabstrip.Add()
        .Text(item.Title)
        .Selected(true)
        .Content(
                 @<text>
                 <div style="width:980px; min-height:562px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px">

                                @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "tabForm" }))
                                {
                                <div>
                                    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
                                    @RenderBody()
                                </div>
                                <div style="padding-top:30px; text-align:center;">
                                   Some stuff in between
                                </div>
                                    @Html.Hidden("NextActionHelper",Model.NextActionHelper)
                                    @Html.Hidden("UserFormAction",Model.UserFormAction)
                                }
                                </div>
                     </text>
                    );
```